# Mach-O linker error adding parse sdk in an existing swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add the parse sdk to an existing project and I'm getting a bunch of Mach-O linker errors from what looks like Facebook references and also from Google Breakpad PFC.

I've added all the frameworks and followed the instructions from parse
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/swift/existing

I am not using the-ObjC linker flag.

What am I doing wrong?

Sample error -

```
 "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookUtils.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtilsV4(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ReadTaskString(unsigned int, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::WriteModuleStream(unsigned int, MDRawModule*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImage::DynamicImage(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, std::string, unsigned long, unsigned int, int) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MDMemoryDescriptor*, std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> > >, MDMemoryDescriptor const&) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned short*, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > >, unsigned long, unsigned short const&) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you add the library properly under search library path?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - which library?  The parse framework?  I added the framework and followed the instructions in the link to the parse guide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add *Accounts.framework* and *Social.framework* to your project (I know that Parse doesn't say so)? And you could add some more details concerning the error (it is hard to know what really is wrong from your description...)

Comment: yes I added those frameworks, full error message added to the body of the description.

Comment: I tried to add all sources and then delete one after the other and I didn't even got the error after deleting the `ParseFacebookUtils` (which is obviously your problem). Did you do anything else than in the instructions like signing in with FB?

Comment: I don't use facebook at all and am only using parse for push - I don't have the facebook framework added.